# Devemos criar um "Wiki completo" para assuntos repetidos com frequência?

Tags: debate, comunidade, wiki-comunitário

No Stackoverflow eles criaram um chamado ["guia definitivo" de autenticação em sites por meio de formulários](https://stackoverflow.com/q/549). Não sei ao certo se o motivo de criarem um tópico desses foi por conta dos usuários começarem a fazer perguntas repetidas sobre o assunto, mas achei interessante a ideia de "guia definitivo".

Aqui, em nossa comunidade, não sei como estão os assuntos perguntados outras linguagens mas se tratando de [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) um clássico é o " como centralizar o elemento ____ ?". Quando falamos em [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) vem o famoso "como atualizar ____ sem *refresh* ?".

Na tag [ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) boa parte das perguntas tratam do mesmo assunto, o que os difere são detalhes mínimos (bem mínimos, mesmo). Nós acabamos nos repetindo sem querer, alguns problemas já foram resolvidos no passado, possuem boas respostas no site mas por um detalhe ou outro acabamos respondendo novamente, novamente e... novamente.

Esses detalhes em sua maioria são "o **meu** código não funciona", alguns usuários não querem pesquisar (as várias perguntas que temos) ou ler (as várias perguntas que temos), querem a solução pronta e isso está deixando o SOpt com cara de fórum — essa parte foi opinião, desculpe.

Bom, há quem prefira responder novamente mas não seria interessante um tópico centralizado com toda informação sobre o assunto? Se mesmo depois de ver o nosso "super mega wiki sobre ajax" o AP não conseguir resolver problema, aí sim creio que o assunto seja mais especifico e precise de uma pergunta.

O que acham?
Gostaria de saber o que a comunidade pensa a respeito disso.

Comment: Existem muitas praticas no SOen interessantes mesmo :) - Infelizmente os guias usados lá nem sempre são incentivados. +1

Comment: Que nem questões de NullPointerException, são sempre a mesma coisa, não tenho muita vontade de respondê-las.

Comment: Em algumas tags, eu adiciono links com perguntas de erros comuns, deixo o link do wiki para o autor da pergunta, isso ai já da uma boa filtrada em problemas simples.

Comment: Nesse ponto, eu acredito que o problema não é (unicamente) a falta de pesquisa em si, mas o fato dos usuários responderem novamente a mesma pergunta. Essa pergunta deveria ser sinalizada como duplicada de uma outra pergunta, que levaria o usuário a resposta desejada, mas essa é só minha opinião...

Comment: Só de htaccess tem 234793 duplicatas abertas no site. Não acho que seja falta de guias especificamente, acho que um problema é o pessoal mesmo vendo que tem 3 votos de duplicata, insistir em responder. Além disso, acho que procurar por perguntas similares também cabe a quem responde. Nem sempre a gente acha na hora, mas é bom conferir. Agora, se acha falta de algum guia de algo específico, nada impede de fazer voluntariamente como pergunta e resposta própria. Outros podem responder com alternativas também.